# PHP Script won't load

Tags: php, apache2

I'm new to web development and have been wrestling with this problem for several hours now, so I've decided to turn to your wisdom.  I'm trying to design a little webpage with a database for my wife to store her recipes in, but I'm having trouble getting form submission to work.  Here is the code for the webpage where I take the form information in:

```
<html><body>
Enter the information below to add a new ingredient for use in your recipes.
<form action="add_to_database.php" method="post">
Name: <input name="name" type="text" />
Serving: <input type="text" name="serving" />
Calories: <input type="text" name="calories" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

And here is some silly code I've been trying to display on the page to see if I can even get the form submission to work:

```
<html><body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name."<br />";
?>
</body></html>
```

Unfortunately, the page comes back as completely back (after I hit the submit button).  What's absolutely baffling to me is that I've copied and pasted the examples from this [page](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) into some files and everything seems to work fine.  So it seems as though apache and php are working correctly, but I'm messing up somewhere along the way.  My apologies in advance if this seems like a stupid question but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: try `echo $_POST['name'];` and see what it returns.

Comment: Do you have an index.php page?  Can you post up add_to_database.php.  If you have an index.php, doing a simple echo 'test'; at the top will see if php is working.  Then you can go from there.

Comment: When you view source in the browser, do you see the <html><body>?  Do you see the PHP source code?

Comment: advice: don't offer to make a system like this for a wife / husband / partner. It will take way longer than you expected and you'll get totally bored and frustrated and if you ever finish it she won't bother using it. I've been there. Buy her a book.

Comment: @rackemup420 echo $_POST['name']; returns the same blank page (my apologies for the misspelling above).

Comment: @iLLin I do have an index.php page which apache put the "It Works!" text into (which is displayed when I load the page) however I can't seem to get "echo 'test'" to work:
<?php
echo 'test'
?>
However I'm still very confused as to why the example on the page I linked to above worked without a hitch (I copied and pasted the two files they describe into separate files in the htdocs folder of my apache folder)

Comment: @thomasrutter Nope, just a blank page.

Comment: @tomfumb I should have put "for" in quotes :).  This is more a project for me to learn a bit about programming webpages.

Comment: This might seem funny, but, I know if you use the same value for "id" and "name" on a form element, it causes oddities.  In your case, I see you're using the value "name" for the attribute "name".  I'd strongly suggest to avoid doing this, in case it causes oddities like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Do you name the other file as add_to_database.php where the form is submitted. Instead you can test on teh same page by removing the add_to_database.php from the form action.

```
form action="" method="post">
    Name: <input name="name" type="text" />
    Serving: <input type="text" name="serving" />
    Calories: <input type="text" name="calories" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and write the php code on the same page as

$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $name;

If this is not working for you. Create a php file named test.php and type phpinfo(); there.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your page is indeed being processed by PHP - obvious question, but does your PHP file have a .php extension?  Do other things like `phpinfo()` or `echo "Test";` work?

Check the error log in /var/log/apache2/error.log or similar (if on Linux, dunno where that'd be on Windows).

Try turning `display_errors` on in the PHP configuration (this is a good idea only for a development install, not a production server).

Answer (score 0):

a bit of a longshot, but if you can verify that php is pro essing the page. Clean up your html, you are missing the dtd, head, and encoding. . hard to say how a browser is going to interpret a form (missing a name attribute) without these.